# #Value! when using a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this VB code

```
Public Function LastVersionOwned(rCol As Range, versionOwned As Range) As Range
    Set LastVersionOwned = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / (rCol = rCol.Find("*", rCol.Cells(1), , , , xlPrevious)), versionOwned)
End Function
```

What is supossed to do is find the last non empty row in a range and then use that value to get the header of the row, but when I use it, it returns #VALUE!
rCol is the range (list of rows where I want to get the last non empty value e.g. C12:F12) and versionOwned are the headers of the tables (also a range, but static C11:F11)

If i use it like this

```
Public Function LastVersionOwned(rCol As Range) As Range
    Set LastVersionOwned rCol.Find("*", rCol.Cells(1), , , , xlPrevious)
End Function
```

And the in excel I do `=LOOKUP(2,1/(C12:F12=LastVersionOwened(C12:F12)),C$11:F$11)`
it Work, any idea how I can fix this bug?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do. Ex: you find the last empty cell in column A, let's say A100. Then you use that value to do what exactly? What does "get the header of the row" mean?

Comment: I'm trying to find the last non-empty cell in a row e.g. (In a range A2:F2 the last non-empty cell could be C:2) cell C2 has a header, let's say that headers for rows A1:F1 are a s d f g h, so If the last non-empty cell is C2 I would like to get the C1 header that would be D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your comparing an 'Array to Array' on your formula, and trying to do the same thing in VBA, which is not possible because your actually comparing a `Range` to a  `Range`.  And to actually compare an 'Array to Array' in VBA will be a little bit more lengthly.  So I've come up with a working alternative for you...

```
Public Function LastVersionOwned(rCol As Range, versionOwned As Range)
    LastVersionOwned = Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Lookup(rCol(1, rCol.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value, rCol, versionOwned)
End Function
```

Let me know if this suits your needs